# How does one use jest-mock-axios to test a function that calls axios.get?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, axios, jest-mock-axios

I wrote a function I'm trying to test. I followed an example on https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios#user-content-using-await-and-async. The only main difference structurally is that I'm using axios.get instead of axios.post. When I run my test the out put is like this:

[image: screenshot of unit test output with error]

Here is the function I wrote that I'm trying to unit test:

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function getConnectionFromApiKey(apiKey, apiKeyUri) {
    const res = await axios.get(apiKeyUri, {
        headers: { "x-hs-apikey": apiKey },
        params: { "applicationGuid": '' }
    });

    const connectionString = res.data.result[0].result.var_value;

    return buildDbConnectionConfig(connectionString, 'xxxx');
}

function buildDbConnectionConfig(connectionString, domainToCheck) {
    // returns an mssql config object
    return {
        ....
    }
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
const mockAxios = require('jest-mock-axios').default; // why does it seem i have to reference the default object?
const apiKeyValidator = require('../apikey');
require("jest-json");

const apiKey = 'abc123';
const apiKeyUrl = '/VerifyAPIKey/';
const expectedCxn = {
    // mssql connection object properties
};

it('should return a database connection object', async () => {
    const promise = apiKeyValidator.getConnectionFromApiKey(apiKey, apiKeyUrl);

    expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(apiKeyUrl, {
        headers: { "x-hs-apikey": apiKey },
        params: { "applicationGuid": "" }
    });

    // simulating a server response
    const responseObj = {
        // resonseObj properties
    };
    mockAxios.mockResponse(responseObj);
 
    const result = await promise;
 
    expect(result).toMatchJSON(expectedCxn);
});
```

#Update

I overlooked the part of the documentation that describes creating axios mocks. So my next question is how to use jest.fn() to setup the mock function. I tried mockAxios.get = jest.fn() but that didn’t seem to do the trick. What am I missing?